# How to use POS tags as the features

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, text, nlp

I am looking forward to know how could I use POS tags as the features in Matlab. Adding partOfSpeechDetails after tokenizing the document has tagged every word with its respective POS. But how could I take these tags as the features to fed into a classifier?(I know several threads are there, yet I am quite confused in these)

As an example, for the sentence, "hello. how are you?", I got the POS details as the following:

```
Token     DocumentNumber    SentenceNumber    LineNumber       Type        Language     PartOfSpeech 
    _______    ______________    ______________    __________    ___________    ________    ______________
    "hello"          1                 1               1         letters           en       interjection  
    "."              1                 1               1         punctuation       en       punctuation   
    "how"            1                 2               1         letters           en       adverb        
    "are"            1                 2               1         letters           en       auxiliary-verb
    "you"            1                 2               1         letters           en       pronoun       
    "?"              1                 2               1         punctuation       en       punctuation
```

Now, how could I take the PartOfSpeech columns as a feature for the sentence?Should I numbering every occurrences of part of speech in a sentence like this following way?

If the sentence has the form like this

```
noun pronoun verb adverb adjective preposition conjunction interjection punctuation
```

then my given sentence would be encoded as

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 2
```

Is it the way of encoding part of speech? And do u shed some light on how many part of speeches are available in Matlab?

Comment: "Is it the way of encoding part of speech?" What kind of classes are you trying to classify sentences into? That's probably the biggest factor in figuring out if sequences of PoS tags are appropriate features for classification.

Comment: @RyanJenkins thanks. i m trying to classify documents based on sentiments

Comment: the approach to vectorize your part of speech with the numbers is the right way, you will get a good matrix in the end to run your algorithm!